# Giving IP to the bridge not to the Ethernet interface

Tags: linux, networking, bridge

Further to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/236618/adding-ip-address-to-a-bridge-interface), what is the philosophy behind adding an IP to the bridge device br0 and not to eth0 that is a part of the bridge. None of the answers to that question satisfied me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding ip address to a bridge interface](http://serverfault.com/questions/236618/adding-ip-address-to-a-bridge-interface)

Comment: It'd be nice if you'd explain why you found those answers unsatisfying (although I admit they're not particularly high-quality).

Comment: Not satisfying because I read them but still not understand, may be because I am new to Linux network administration

Comment: It would be nice to link me to a page containing graphs or information for newbies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to think about a Linux bridge is that it consists of two parts:

- A virtual switch, which you can plug network cables into by attaching a physical NIC; and
- A "virtual NIC" that is what connects the machine's own network stack to the virtual switch.

Confusingly, they both have the same name.

When you create a bridge and place a physical NIC into the bridge, that physical NIC no longer acts like a NIC, it is, instead, just a network cable (at least, that's the easiest way to think about it).  So, since you need to have a NIC to associate an IP address with, you use the "virtual NIC" that's a part of the bridge.

I'd draw some ASCII art, but I suck at that, so you'll just have to visualise it...